# Small Delay between tasks

Tags: c#

I have a application which changes a backColor of a panel.
I then want it to wait approximately 5 seconds then change the backColor back to original value.  I have tried using Thread.Sleep(5000), but it doesn't delay the execution of the next loop.  I have searched for the last two days trying to find a answer to this porblem.  I'm still fairly new to programming.  So using advances techniques doesn't help me understand the process.
Here is the code which I have tried:

```
StringBuilder MovesText = new StringBuilder(MovesTxt.Text);  


//Start White Horizonal Drill    


for (int Row = 7; Row > 3; --Row)
{
    chessBoardPanels[ Column ,Row].BackColor = Color.Red;
    ++Column;
    //Add text to Moves TextBox
    MovesText.AppendFormat("WhtB               {0}                   {1}{2}",
                           ColumnText,RowText,Environment.NewLine);
    MovesTxt.Text = MovesText.ToString();
    ++ColumnText;
    --RowText;

}
Thread.Sleep(5000);  //This is where I want a 5 second delay

//Start White Horizonal 
Column = 0;
for (int Row = 7; Row > 4; --Row)
{
    chessBoardPanels[Column, Row].BackColor = Color.White;
    ++Column;
    //Add text to Moves TextBox

    ++ColumnText;
    --RowText;

}
```

Comment: Can you give us more information ? Do you create a thread somewhere ?

Comment: `Thread.Sleep()` most certainly would delay the second loop's execution, but the result might not be what you're looking for.  If there's a UI waiting for this overall method to complete, that UI isn't going to see any updates at all until everything completes.  How you update that UI is going to depend on the UI technology you're using.  As a general approach, you'll want to move the second loop into its own thread so that the program control can return to the UI after the first loop.  (Or perhaps even put the first loop in its own thread as well.)  *That* thread should be delayed.

Comment: try using  TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.00f);

Comment: @pravin How would that help?...

Answer (score 0):

The way I have approached problems like this in the past is using the Update() method.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are creating some form of Windows application then you can use a [timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Replace the line where you call Thread.Sleep with code to start the timer

and create a TimerElapsed event handler to reset the colour.

Comment: Could you please give example of TimerElasped event handler

Comment: Have a look at this [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed(v=vs.110).aspx)